# Reverse Proxy to Remote Host NGINX in Docker Container Not Working

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy, backend

I have a flask backend server currently running in gcloud that is accessible via a hard-coded IP address at `XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8000`. This server is open to the public web and I can access it from my localhost. I am trying to proxy port 5000 through nginx to hit this backend server. For now, I have simply hard-coded the IP address for testing. Here is my nginx **.conf** file:

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

  sendfile        on;

  keepalive_timeout  65;
  upstream faststyle_local {
      server XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8000;
  }

  server {

    listen       80;
    server_name  frontend;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

  }

  server {
    listen  5000;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://faststyle_local;
    }

  }
}
```

When I start the server locally with `nginx -c nginx.conf` the server works fine and I am correctly proxied to the backend server when I hit **localhost:5000**.

However, when I try to run this same server in a docker container, the proxy at **localhost:5000** doesn't work.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/default.conf
COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Which I am starting with:

`docker run -it -p 80:80 -p 5000:5000 IMAGE_NAME`

All of the questions that I have seen regarding this issue involve linking to a locally running Docker container that is not visible to the containerized nginx server. This is not my issue because I am simply trying to proxy to an IP address that is running on the public web. I am fairly new to nginx so I could be missing something obvious in my **.conf** file.

Comment: What do the docker nginx logs say?

Comment: There is no response from the server when I get localhost:5000. The request isn't being received at all.